# How to simplify checking if an iterator returned by a search algorithm is valid?

Tags: c++, find

Yesterday I was lucky enough to see a question that existed for quite a short period of time and was deleted while I was writing an answer to it (I guess that the question was deleted by the author, who was convinced by commenters that his/her proposal didn't make much sense). I am reformulating that question in a slightly more general way and providing my answer to it. Other ideas and/or pointers to existing implementations of my idea (which I failed to quickly find) are welcome too.

The following is quite a frequent pattern of using a search operation (below example uses the member function `find()` of `std::map`, but it can also be re-written via the `std::find` or `std::lower_bound` algorithms):

```
const auto it = map.find(key);     // 1
if ( it != map.end() )             // 2
{
    do something with it
}
```

Though the pattern looks quite short, the code can become more cluttered if the map object has a significantly longer name or is referenced through a complex expression like below:

```
const auto it = p->getMappingFor(currentConfig()->whatever()).find(key);
```

Is there a way of collapsing the lines 1 and 2 in the example above into one and have the map object referenced only once?

**EDIT 1:**

The motivation for simplifying this *find-and-check* pattern is similar to the one that led to the appearance of the [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) as a more convenient form of the [traditional `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).

Comment: Use ranges instead of iterators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest form of looking up something in a container and immediately checking the validity of the returned iterator is this:

```
if (const auto it = find_in(container, something))
{
    do something with it
}
```

For this to compile, the type of `it` must be convertible to `bool`. (It goes without saying that `it` must derive from the regular iterator type that would be returned by the underlying search operation). Below code contains the implementation of the `find_in()` utility for `std::vector` and `std::map`. Adding overloads for other containers is trivial.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<class It>
class OptionalIterator : public It
{
    It end_;

public:
    OptionalIterator(It it, It end) : It(it), end_(end) {}

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return static_cast<const It&>(*this) != end_;
    }
};

////////////////////// find_in() a range ///////////////////////////////////

template<class It, class X>
OptionalIterator<It>
find_in(It start, It end, const X& x)
{
    return OptionalIterator<It>(std::find(start, end, x), end);
}

////////////////////// find_in() a std::vector /////////////////////////////

template<class T, class A, class X>
OptionalIterator<typename std::vector<T, A>::const_iterator>
find_in(const std::vector<T, A>& v, const X& x)
{
    return find_in(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
}

template<class T, class A, class X>
OptionalIterator<typename std::vector<T, A>::iterator>
find_in(std::vector<T, A>& v, const X& x)
{
    return find_in(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
}

////////////////////// find_in() a std::map ////////////////////////////////

template<class K, class V, class C, class A, class X>
OptionalIterator<typename std::map<K, V, C, A>::const_iterator>
find_in(const std::map<K, V, C, A>& m, const X& x)
{
    typedef typename std::map<K, V, C, A>::const_iterator It;
    return OptionalIterator<It>(m.find(x), m.end());
}

template<class K, class V, class C, class A, class X>
OptionalIterator<typename std::map<K, V, C, A>::iterator>
find_in(std::map<K, V, C, A>& m, const X& x)
{
    typedef typename std::map<K, V, C, A>::iterator It;
    return OptionalIterator<It>(m.find(x), m.end());
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{2, 4, 1, 3};
    if ( const auto it = find_in(v, 4) )
            std::cout << "4 in v is at index " << it - v.begin() << std::endl;

    std::map<int, int> m{{1, 23}, {4, 56}};
    if ( const auto it = find_in(m, 4) )
            std::cout << "m[4]=" << it->second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An iterator, 'on it's own', is not convertible to bool. In fact, that conversion should return true in one case and false in another if you allow views.

Comment: This will not work with pointers so unfortunately it is not generic enough

Comment: Add C-style array to your example so we can see how

Comment: @Slava I don't want the answer to be filled with details that will distract from the main idea. It can definitely be done by wrapping pointers into a special iterator type like it is done for `std::vector` but also providing implicit conversion to the wrapped pointer type.

Comment: @Leon that's not just details, it is a problem that ruins whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of collapsing the lines 1 and 2 in the example below into one and have the map object referenced only once?

I don't clearly understand the motivation for this. Combining multiple queries into a one liner results in code that is more difficult to understand and debug. I am going to suggest making the 2 liner into a 3 liner instead of a 1 liner.

```
auto const& theMap = p->getMappingFor(currentConfig()->whatever());
auto const it = theMap.find(key);
if ( it != theMap.end() )
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++17 we will have [If statements with initializer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html).

We can then write

```
if (const auto it = theMap.find(key); it != theMap.end() ) {
   ...
}
```

A benefit of this is that the iterator lives inside the scope of the `if` only, including the possible `else` clause.

Comment: This is not really an answer to OP's question as he wants theMap to be referenced only once